# How do I get an IF Else statement to work for ASP

Tags: asp.net

I need a simple .NET ASP IF ELSE Statement, but I can't get anything to work. All the examples I find online do not have these weird brackets:

```
 <% {%>  <%} %>
```

And apparently the system I'm using needs them to work.

Here is the code snippet I have that is working fine:

```
<% if (User.RepID != null) { %> 

    <form id="repUrlCheck" action="http://example.com/example.php" method="post">

        <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.RepPhone1) && User.RepPhone1.Trim().ToString().Length > 0) { %>
            <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<%= User.RepPhone1 %>">
        <%} %>

        ...

    </form>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("repUrlCheck").submit();
        });
    </script>

<%} %>
```

What I need is an Else statement for the initial IF

The best I could come up with is:

```
<% if (User.RepID != null) { %> 

    <form id="repUrlCheck" action="http://example.com/example.php" method="post">

        <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.RepPhone1) && User.RepPhone1.Trim().ToString().Length > 0) { %>
            <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<%= User.RepPhone1 %>">
        <%} %>

        ...

    </form>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("repUrlCheck").submit();
        });
    </script>

<%} 
Else { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    </script>
<%}
End If
%>
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me how to write this kind of IF ELSE code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SLakes said C# is case sensitive and there is no `End If` in c#.

```
    <% if (User.RepID != null) { %> 

    <form id="repUrlCheck" action="http://example.com/example.php" method="post">

        <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.RepPhone1) && User.RepPhone1.Trim().ToString().Length > 0)          { %>
            <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<%= User.RepPhone1 %>">
        <%} %>

        ...

    </form>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("repUrlCheck").submit();
        });
    </script>

<%} 
else { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    </script>
<%}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is case-sensitive.

`else` must be lowercase.

Comment: And, there's no End If in C#.

Comment: this worked perfect with lowercase else and getting rid of End If